# Update multiple rows in SQL data

Tags: sql

While trying to update multiple rows using UPDATE (code given below), it updates all the rows with the one which appears in the last row. Please help sort this out.

My code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("my_db");

if( isset($_POST["submit"])){
foreach( $_POST["id"] AS $id) {

$FA1 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA1']);
$FA2 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA2']);
$FA3 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA3']);   

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="UPDATE product_tbl SET Agency='$FA1', Material='$FA2', Category='$FA3' WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1 ";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

// if successfully upDated.

```
if($result){    
echo "<script>alert('Data upDated Successfully in the DB')</script>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<script>window.open('edit.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

How do I get the result?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the foreach loop the variable $FA1, $FA2, $FA3 are fetching the same value again as it is getting values directly from form data

```
$FA1 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA1']);
$FA2 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA2']);
$FA3 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['FA3']);
```

This will fetch the data from the form you submitted